# MYSQL select query in PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel and I am trying to receive the clasa_id from the clasa table in the elevi table.

```
    $clasa = new Clasa();
    $clasa->cifra = \Auth::user()->clasa_cifra;
    $clasa->litera = \Auth::user()->clasa_litera;
    $clasa->save();


    $elev = new Elevi();
    $elev->nume = $request['nume'];
    $elev->prenume = $request['prenume'];
    $elev->clasa_id = ?????
    $elev->save();
```

Firstly in the clasa table I add the clasa_cifra and clasa_litera, and generate an auto increment clasa_id and I want to make a

```
select 'clasa_id' from 'clasa' where 'clasa_cifra=\Auth::user()->clasa_cifra, clasa_litera=\Auth::user()->clasa_litera'
```

and add it to the clasa_id from the elevi table

how to implement it? Thank you!

Comment: Is the `Clasa` and `Elevi` codes right next to each other? You can just do `$elev->clasa_id = $clasa->id`, if so.

Comment: I am working in laravel5, and I have 2 different controllers for Clasa and Elevi. The clasa_id is and auto_increment in the clasa table, where I have a lot of classes (like 10A, 10B) and I want to get the id of a certain class

Comment: I mean in this case I will always send in elevi table a new generated id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option is to pass the `$clasa` object in the function where you are creating `Elevi::class` and use it as:

```
$clasa->id
```

If passing object is not an option then you can write query to fetch the corresponding `$clasa` object as:

```
$clasa = Clasa::where('cifra', \Auth::user()->clasa_cifra)
        ->where('litera', \Auth::user()->clasa_litera)
        ->select('id')
        ->first()
```

and you can get the id by using `$clasa->id`

Comment: what does the ->first() function do?

Comment: and why in id_clasa i get the value:  " {"id_clasa":5} " but not only 5?

Comment: For your first question, refer [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) link and I didn't get your second question.